# java - Can someone explain to me what is going on? there's a lot of things going on in which I haven't been taught yet

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
     increase(x);
     Reverse rev = new Reverse();
     rev.reverse(x);
     System.out.println(x[0] + " " + x[1] + " " + x[2]);
   }

   //Increase every element in the array by 1
   //For example: array : 0, 1, 2 will become 1, 2, 3
   public static void increase(int[] a) {
       //TODO: FILL ME
   }
}

class Reverse {
     //Reverse the array
     //For example: array 0, 1, 2 will become 2, 1, 0
     public void reverse(int[] a) {
           //TODO: FILL ME
     }
}
```

What does increase(x); do ? Basically I have to fill in where he wrote fill in. But its kind of hard when i dont even understand what is going on.

Comment: are u doing your school assignments?

Comment: yeah i have 4.5 hours till the sun rises lol.

Comment: I had 3 assignments the first one took me like 5 hours :(

Comment: Right now, increase(x) does nothing. I guess someone will have to write code there.

Comment: and the lesson here is to start your assignments earlier, I guess.

Comment: yeah time to get crackign 4.5 hours to go hehe

Comment: yeah it looked easy...i mean it is easy for u guys at least

Comment: Congratulations.  This is the first of _many_ deadlines you will meet in your career where the estimates were off.

Comment: well the deadline passed so if anyone wants to post it so i can learn please do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now `increase()` does nothing for now.
Your assignment is to write the content of the method in a way that will increase the content of every cell of your array.

**What does your code do?**

```
 int[] x = {1, 2, 3}; // Create an array with 3 elements, "1", "2" and "3"
 increase(x); // Call the increase() method which for now does nothing
 Reverse rev = new Reverse(); // Create an instance of the Reverse class, which contains a method to reverse arrays (but does nothing for now)
 rev.reverse(x); // Call the famous reverse() method.
 System.out.println(x[0] + " " + x[1] + " " + x[2]); //Print the content of you array x[0] is the first cell, x[1] the second, etc.
```

Comment: hmm...so i guess i have to use it i was just going to do the easier way and assign new arrays but i guess i have to find a way to use it

Comment: You can't create new arrays, all you have to do is loop through your array (you have already seen that I hope) and do an operation to increment the content of the cell.

Comment: hm..does it matter that there's 2 public static void? thats the first time I see it so far. Whats the benefit of having 2 versus doing it all under one like my other homework before?

Comment: It's isn't a problem as long as the two methods don't have the same *prototype*. There is only one `main()` and it is your entry point the other is just another method called in your application.

Comment: so increase(x) should have meaning in the code that im suppose to write?

Comment: i can do System.out.println(a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + (a[1]+a[1]));
lol it gives me the result but i know for sure that is not what he wants me to do lol

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/java-clone-method.shtml am i suppose to do it like that?

Comment: No you're just suppose to modify directly the array you get in parameter

Comment: but i thought that when you modify whatever is in the parameter you essentially modify both x and a since they both point to the same reference?

Comment: exactly, that's the point. As your increase method doesn't return anything you have to handle the modification directly on the array.

Comment: public static void increase(int[] a) { int i = 0; for ( a[i] = a[0]; a[i] < 3; i++ ); { System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2]); }

Comment: i just ended up doing that...its probably wrong but ...a for effort i guess

Comment: instead of doing a System.out, you have to increment the value of a[i] :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement `increase(x)` calls the static method `increase(int[] a)`.

As the method just contains a comment, it effectively does nothing. Looks like your tutor wants you to replace the `//TODO: FILL ME` comment with code that implements the increase method correctly. Your tutor has described what the code should do in the comments above the method;

```
//Increase every element in the array by 1
//For example: array : 0, 1, 2 will become 1, 2, 3
```

Good luck!

Comment: hm..im still stuck can you help me out even more

Comment: You just need to do what your tutor has indicated; in the increase method, increment the int values in the array you are passed as the parameter. In the reverse method, reverse the order of the elements in the array you are passed. Aside from actually writing the code for you, I'm not sure how much more help I can give?

Comment: public static void increase(int[] a) {
   int i = 0;
   for ( a[i] = a[0]; a[i] < 3; i++ );
   {
  
      
       System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2]);
       } am i on the right track?

Comment: aiyahh oh well i give up thanks tho. i'll understand it one day lol gooooood night

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is in the increase method, iterate through all the values in the integer array "a" using a for loop. You should then assign an integer that's 1 more than the current integer to itself.

I'm so tempted to post a solution but that'll teach you nothing!

Comment: OH the deadline already passed so you can lol at least this way I can learn it. The tutor isn't going to go over until the next lecture

Comment: so i'm guessing that you never got to do it.